# How can I center the following boxes using CSS

Tags: html, css, css-float

I am trying to center the boxes horizontally. Currently they are aligned to the left and when you resize the window they move responsively. I would still like to keep that functionality. I just want to center the boxes even when I resize the window. I tried float:center but there is no such thing...Thank you.

http://jsfiddle.net/9BB36/9/

```
.mybtn {
font:bold 20px"Arial Black", Gadget, sans-serif;
font-style:normal;
color:#ffd324;

background-color: rgba(255,0,0,.90);
border:2px solid #000;
text-shadow:0px -1px 1px #222222;
box-shadow:0px 0px 12px #2e2300;
-moz-box-shadow:0px 0px 12px #2e2300;
-webkit-box-shadow:0px 0px 12px #2e2300;
border-radius:15px 15px 15px 15px;
-moz-border-radius:15px 15px 15px 15px;
-webkit-border-radius:15px 15px 15px 15px;
width:100px;
height:100px;
margin:5px;
float:left;
position:relative;
}
```

And the HTML

```
<div class="mybtn">

</div>

<div class="mybtn">

</div>

<div class="mybtn">

</div>

<div class="mybtn">

</div>

<div class="mybtn">

</div>
```

Comment: No, I don't mean vertically. If you extend your window far enough you will see that the boxes are aligned to the left...and there is much more space on the right side

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could wrap them in a div, apply `text-align:center` to it, then remove the float on the `.mybtn` divs and change the display to inline-block.

```
#wrapper {
    text-align:center;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/4CTZ7/)**

Comment: That's exactly what I'm looking for. Is there any other way to do it besides putting them inside a div wrapper? Thanks

Comment: Yes if they are only thing on the page use `body { text-align: center; }`

Comment: These buttons need to reside somewhere in your layout.  The centering will be with respect to the containing block.

Answer (score 0):

As j08691 said:

You could wrap them in a div, apply `text-align:center` to it, then remove the float on the `.mybtn` divs and change the display to inline-block but rather than using a `<div>` use `<section>` tag as the `<div>` tag should be avoided in HTML5, when referring to a "section" of the page.

So the new code would look like:

**HTML**:

```
<section>
    <div class="transparent-btn"></div>
    <div class="transparent-btn"></div>
    <div class="transparent-btn"></div>
    <div class="transparent-btn"></div>
    <div class="transparent-btn"></div>
</section>
```

**CSS**:

```
section {
    text-align: auto;
}

.transparent-btn {
    font:bold 20px"Arial Black", Gadget, sans-serif;
    font-style:normal;
    color:#ffd324;
    display: inline;
    background-color: rgba(255,0,0,.90);
    border:2px solid #000;
    text-shadow:0px -1px 1px #222222;
    box-shadow:0px 0px 12px #2e2300;
    -moz-box-shadow:0px 0px 12px #2e2300;
    -webkit-box-shadow:0px 0px 12px #2e2300;
    border-radius:15px 15px 15px 15px;
    -moz-border-radius:15px 15px 15px 15px;
    -webkit-border-radius:15px 15px 15px 15px;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;


    margin:5px;
    position:relative;


}
```